# How can i add two WHERE statement in MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query of MySQL,

```
return $this->resultQuery("SELECT COUNT(home_id) AS total 
    FROM `".$this->table_prefix."user_homes` 
    WHERE user_id = $assign_id ". 
    ($home_cfg_id ? 'AND `home_cfg_id` IN (
        SELECT `home_cfg_id` 
        FROM `'.$this->table_prefix.'server_homes` 
        WHERE home_cfg_id = '.$home_cfg_id' )': ''));
```

but still got error when i run this query

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: combine your dynamic SQL statement to a string and then print the string then post that.  the SQL is likely wrong syntactically somewhere.

Comment: You're missing a `.` after `$home_cfg_id`.

Comment: LOL, yes you are right, i missing a `.`. Thank you.

Comment: Please set this as answer to edit this to solved.

Comment: @ObadaDiab Happens to the best of us. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I'm putting this in an answer. You are missing a concatenating `.` at the end of your query string, after `$home_cfg_id`.

When debugging something like this, it is often helpful to do as @xQbert suggested, and output the sql string. This will allow you to review the query for anything that looks wrong - as well as (possibly) give a clearer PHP error if the string is created incorrectly.

```
return $this->resultQuery("SELECT COUNT(home_id) AS total 
    FROM `".$this->table_prefix."user_homes` 
    WHERE user_id = $assign_id ". 
    ($home_cfg_id ? 'AND `home_cfg_id` IN (
        SELECT `home_cfg_id` 
        FROM `'.$this->table_prefix.'server_homes` 
        WHERE home_cfg_id = '.$home_cfg_id.' )': ''));
                                          ^
```

Comment: Of course, with the syntax error he couldn't echo the sql string, because the code doesn't even run.

Comment: Yeah, that's part of what I was getting at when I ended with the bit about giving a clearer PHP error if the string is created incorrectly. It'll help direct the developer to look at the string itself, rather than be concerned that the function (`resultQuery`) has a problem with the input - or even that the DB server doesn't like the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug SQL by staring at code that builds the SQL. It's also hard to use string concatenation syntax without making a mistake.

Here are some tips to make this kind of debugging a lot easier:

**Tip 1:** Reference variables inside strings instead of using `.` concatenation.

```
$string = 'part 1' . $variable . 'part 2';
```

can also be written:

```
$string = "part1{$variable}part2";
```

The curly braces are optional, unless your variable name would run into the following literal text, or if you use complex PHP objects and arrays:

```
$string = "part1{$var['key']}part2{$obj->field}part3";
```

But I like to use the curly braces consistently when putting variables into strings, because it makes it easy to see where the PHP variables are.

**Tip 2:** Use temporary variables:

```
$user_homes = "{$this->table_prefix}user_homes";
$server_homes = "{$this->table_prefix}server_homes";
```

**Tip 3:** Build your SQL query before you use it. Avoid the ternary operator `?:`, use `if()` instead. You'll need it anyway for some cases, so you might as well be consistent.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(home_id) AS total 
  FROM `{$user_homes}` 
  WHERE user_id = {$assign_id}";
if ($home_cfg_id) {
    $sql .= " AND `home_cfg_id` IN (
      SELECT `home_cfg_id` 
      FROM `{$server_homes}` 
      WHERE home_cfg_id = {$home_cfg_id}";
}

// Here you can log the SQL query if you need to debug

return $this->resultQuery($sql);
```

This makes your code easier to read, easier to debug, easier to modify.